# User shown in ps does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, user-management, ps

This is strange:

```
» ps -ef | grep gitlab
gitlab-+ 19663  4237  0 06:45 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
```

But the `gitlab-+` user does not exist:

```
» cat /etc/passwd | grep gitlab
gitlab-www:x:998:997::/var/opt/gitlab/nginx:/bin/false
git:x:997:996::/var/opt/gitlab:/bin/sh
gitlab-redis:x:996:995::/var/opt/gitlab/redis:/bin/false
gitlab-psql:x:995:994::/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql:/bin/sh
gitlab-prometheus:x:994:993::/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus:/bin/sh
```

Why could that be?

How can I tell `ps` to show me the user id instead of the user name, for all entries?

Answer (score 3):

Use `n` parameter, described in manual page:

```
n      Numeric output for WCHAN and USER (including all types of UID and GID)
```

e.g

```
ps -ef n
```

N.B. there should be space, not dash before `n`

Answer (score 2):

The + sign at the end of the UID field just means "the username is longer than 8 characters and did not fit here".

For historical reasons, the field widths of `ps -ef` output have been kept as they are, even when usernames longer than 8 characters have become common: mostly because there are a lot of scripts that parse its output and would fail in mysterious ways if the field widths would change.